# making @XmlElements dynamic

Tags: java, annotations, jaxb, java-annotations

The docs for the annotation type [`@XmlElements`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElements.html) has this example:

```
public class Foo {
    @XmlElements(
        @XmlElement(name="A", type=Integer.class),
        @XmlElement(name="B", type=Float.class)
     }
     public List items;
}
```

This is great when you only have a few known types that need to be in the list.  I am looking for a way to make it more dynamic so that when new elements are added to the system class `Foo` does not need to be modified.

The first thing that comes to mind is using some custom annotations. Lets call it `@XmlElementType` and it has a attribute of type which would be applied to the elements (`Integer`, `Float`, etc).  Of course this cannot be done to predefined types, it would only apply to new types.

Then an variant of the annotation `@XmlElements` would be applied to the `List` items in class `Foo`.  It would have a attribute to indicate the type of `@XmlElementType` which it can contain, maybe a package to scan for the POJO's.

So I have two questions:

1. Does something like this already exist?
2. If not, can something like this be implemented? If so, now?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use type of Object.class and then use [XmlAnyElement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAnyElement.html). If you can give a concrete example, what you want to achieve, then it will be possible for me to edit the answer and give concrete example.